# export data to excel showing data instand of downloading php

Tags: php, excel, download

I have code

```
<?php
    $developersData= array( 
        array("NAME" => "John Doe", "EMAIL" => "john.doe@gmail.com", "GENDER" => "Male", "COUNTRY" => "United States"), 
        array("NAME" => "Gary Riley", "EMAIL" => "gary@hotmail.com", "GENDER" => "Male", "COUNTRY" => "United Kingdom"), 
        array("NAME" => "Edward Siu", "EMAIL" => "siu.edward@gmail.com", "GENDER" => "Male", "COUNTRY" => "Switzerland"), 
        array("NAME" => "Betty Simons", "EMAIL" => "simons@example.com", "GENDER" => "Female", "COUNTRY" => "Australia"), 
        array("NAME" => "Frances Lieberman", "EMAIL" => "lieberman@gmail.com", "GENDER" => "Female", "COUNTRY" => "United Kingdom") 
    );
    $fileName = "export_".date('Ymd') . ".xls";
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"");  
    $showColoumn = false;
    if(!empty($developersData)) {
      foreach($developersData as $developerInfo) {
        if(!$showColoumn) {      
          echo implode("\t", array_keys($developerInfo)) . "\n";
          $showColoumn = true;
        }
        echo implode("\t", array_values($developerInfo)) . "\n";
      }
    }
    ?>
```

before it was working fine but now its not working with browser

its showing only data not getting file downloaded

i have taken reference form https://www.codexworld.com/export-data-to-excel-in-php/

Comment: Can you please post  your output??

Comment: @Shoshana  : https://3v4l.org/6M6Ba

Comment: You can use PHPexcel